# Mysql Query to find near duplicate urls

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to eliminate duplicate domain names (URL's) in a mysql DB table.

I've used this query to find "same" urls:

```
SELECT URL, 
COUNT(*) c 
FROM Links 
GROUP BY URL 
HAVING c > 1;
```

But this query fails to find same domain different urls which is what i need:

```
example.com
www.example.com
www.example.com/
www.example.com/somepage.htm
```

Any help would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the last three cases pretty easily:

```
select min(url), count(*) as c
from links
group by substring_index(url, '/', 1)
having c > 1;
```

To get the first, I would recommend removing `www.` at the beginning of the string.  The following should work (although it will fail if `.www` occurs later in the url before the first `/`):

```
select min(url), count(*) as c
from links
group by (case when url like 'www.%' then substring(substring_index(url, '/', 1), 5)
               else substring_index(url, '/', 1)
           end)
having c > 1;
```

Comment: Its returning a lot of values for this one url: 09-car-example.com

Comment: @JamieGallicchio . . . Jamie, this answers follows the rules you specified in your question.  If your examples are really more complicated, I would suggest that you ask another question with more detailed examples.  If you edit this question, you will invalidate my answer which can draw downvotes.

Comment: actually your reply doesn't return same domain names.  In theory it looks like it should work, but it fails to return any similar domains.  it actually groups them all in to two groups.  it doesn't even filter out the same domain name with one ending in / and the other just in the domain extension. The only thing that could be effecting this is that all the urls start with http:// in the database. Thank you for your attempt.

Comment: @JamieGallicchio . . . If the data is different from what is in your question, then the results probably won't hold.  Try running the query on the examples you give.  If the names start with `http://` then the argument to substring_index should probably be 3 instead of 1.